# Geometrical Shapes for Discrete Probability Distributions

Tags: probability, geometry, recreational-mathematics

A regular 6 sided die, which is geometrically a cube, implicitly represents a discrete uniform density over the set {1,2,3,4,5,6}. After tossing the die, any face of the cube has the same probability of ending face-down on the ground.

My (handwavy) questions are the following: Do all discrete probability distributions have an associated "geometrical-die"? If so, is the relationship one-to-one or can multiple die represent the same pmf? Given a pmf how does one construct such a die, and vice versa?

Comment: As you say, this is quite vague...but it seems fair to imagine that whatever you mean by a "geometrical die" it would give you a distribution with all rational probabilities.  Thus you couldn't get, say, a distribution on $\{0,1\}$ with the probability of getting $0$ equal to $\sqrt 2 - 1$.

Comment: Further, you have some discrete distributions with infinite support (*infinitely many possible outcomes*).  No such "geometrical-die" would have infinitely many sides under any natural interpretation of your term.

Comment: As for "is the relationship one-to-one?"  It is unclear what you would consider for one "die" to be different than another, but you might consider a [barrel d20](https://in.pinterest.com/pin/195836283783508922/) to be "different" than an [icosohedral d20](http://millerpadsandpaper.com/20-sided-die/).  If you insist on the die being of some regular shape, without careful phrasing of what you want you might limit yourself just to the five [platonic solids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platonic_solid).